# Как отправить видео в aiogram3 по ссылке

Tags: python, aiogram-3.x

Я делаю бота, который должен будет отправлять определённые видео. Самый лучший способ это сделать — это отправлять эти видео по ссылке из файлообменника. Но как отправлять в aiogram видео по ссылке я не нашёл. Объясните, пожалуйста, как это сделать, или поделитесь ресурсами, где понятно объясняют.

Comment: А на файлообменнике будет прямая ссылка? Кроме того, для такого способа у телеграм есть ограничения на размер файлов. А вообще, рекомендованным способом отправки файлов является отправка по file_id